# Custom binning in seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am new to `seaborn`, and I'm currently playing around with the `pairplot` functionalities... With the following

```
seaborn.pairplot(data,
                 hue="Class",
                 diag_king="hist",
                 diag_kws={'alpha'=0.5}
                 )
```

I'm able to achieve most of what I want: a grid of scatter plots from my `pandas` dataframe `data`, with separated distributions according to the `Class` column, and semi-transparent histograms along the diagonal.

I've figured out that by passing `bin=[...]` to `diag_kws` I can have *all diagonal plots* adopt that binning, but I'd like each column of my dataframe to take its binning from a dedicated dictionary (with keys the column names).

Is it possible to achieve this with `diag_kws`? Or do I need to access each of the diagonal plots individually after calling `pairplot` and rebin them manually? What's the most efficient way?

Comment: `PairGrid` offers [`map_diag`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.map_diag.html#seaborn.PairGrid.map_diag) which one could use to map a custom function which changes the parameters in each call.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the suggestion! I see how I can use `pyplot` methods with `map_diag`, but how do I go about building a custom function that accesses the name of the variable being plotted?

Comment: I guess there is no equivalent of `FacetGrid`'s `map_dataframe` for `PairGrid`, right? In that case one needs to be creative. E.g. the number of times the function gets called is an indication for which axes it currently works on, or the current axes' position in the grid... I haven't tried any of this though.

Comment: Ok, after calling `g = seaborn.pairplot(...)`, I can then loop over the diagonal elements of `g.axes` and try setting the bins there... It seems overly hacky, but I guess it'll have to do... :)

Comment: Mhh, that's not what I meant, but it's equally possible of course. I provided my suggestion as answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PairGrid` offers [`map_diag`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.map_diag.html#seaborn.PairGrid.map_diag) which one could use to map a custom function which changes the parameters in each call. This could look like this. Mind that one needs to take care of the order (via `vars` argument) to make sure the correct parameters are applied.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


iris = sns.load_dataset("iris", cache=True)
col_list = ['petal_length', 'petal_width', 'sepal_length', 'sepal_width'] 
cols = iter(col_list)

bins = {'sepal_length' : 10, 'sepal_width' : 5, 
        'petal_length' : 35, 'petal_width' : 12}


def myhist(x, **kwargs):
    b = bins[next(cols)]
    plt.text(0.5,0.9, f"bins = {b}", ha="center", 
             transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
    plt.hist(x, bins=b, **kwargs)


g = sns.PairGrid(iris, vars=col_list)
g = g.map_diag(myhist)
g = g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using `pairplot`, how do I set the axes for each plot? I have a 4 by 4 plot, with different ranging values.